# Json.Net and validation of Enums in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm writing a web api in .Net Core 2.2. I have an enumeration as follows:

using System.Runtime.Serialization;

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public enum MyEnum
    {
        [EnumMember(Value = "Some Value")]
        SomeValue
    }
}
```

If I pass in random data as MyEnum in a request using the enum I rightly get an error, but if I pass "Some Value" or "SomeValue" it passes. How do I make "SomeValue" invalid? "SomeValue" isn't in my swagger and isn't a value I want to accept.

So basically, model validation passes for "SomeValue" when that isn't really valid.

Any ideas how I can make only "Some Value" valid? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I Understand Correctly the Question.You Can Use This Sample For Get 'Some Value' Instead Of 'SomeValue':

> using System.ComponentModel;

```
 public enum MyEnum
    {
        [Description("Some Value")]
        SomeValue
    }
```

**Create StringEnumExtension Class :**

```
public static class StringEnumExtension
    {
        public static string GetDescription<T>(this T e) 
        {
            string str = (string) null;

            if ((object) e is Enum)
            {
                Type type = e.GetType();
                foreach (int num in Enum.GetValues(type))
                {
                    if (num == Convert.ToInt32(e, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                    {
                        object[] customAttributes = type.GetMember(type.GetEnumName((object) num))[0]
                            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
                        if ((uint) customAttributes.Length > 0U)
                        {
                            str = ((DescriptionAttribute) customAttributes[0]).Description;
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return str;
        }
    }
```

**Then Use the Code Below to Call :**

```
 var result = MyEnum.SomeValue.GetDescription();
```

Comment: Hi, no I think I've confused you. When submitting a request in a web api both "SomeValue" and "Some Value" are valid in the request.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with Enums in the past, even with the `EnumMember` attribute and the default `StringEnumConverter`.

I ended up with a custom converter that inherits from `StringEnumConverter` which reads `EnumMember` and parses the given string value to the enum member: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58338955/225808

I've tested my code with additional spaces and I get validate errors when using my code. I anonymized my code and this should work for you:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "weather requires a valid value")]
[JsonProperty("weather")]
public WeatherEnum? Weather { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi, am I missing something, but CanConvert never gets called,

Comment: Yes. I did not link any code with `CanConvert`. Please refer to the code of my linked question and combine it with the code I wrote in this answer.

Comment: Hi citronas... I looked at your code but CanConvert never triggers in my effort. Are you sure it's triggered if decorating properties?

Comment: Please show me the code with `CanConvert`. I can't find it